# jQuery eventData undefined when placed in interval/timeout function

Tags: jquery, events, handler, setinterval

EDIT: See comments for how I don't know how to use events at a basic level (and the answer)

I feel like this should be an easy fix, but I've been pulling my hair out about it for the past hour.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#score svg").mousedown(event.data, scoreDrag);
});
```

Which works perfectly fine, event is defined.

But I don't want the handler to be assigned until some function in a different script (defined before this one) has finished making all the SVGs in #score

So what I've done is define a global variable in the script that makes the SVGs (SVGloaded) that isn't true until it finishes making all the SVGS - a là:

```
var isSVGloaded;

$(document).ready(function() {
    isSVGloaded = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (SVGloaded) {
            $("#score svg").mousedown(event.data, scoreDrag);
            window.clearInterval(isSVGloaded);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Which, DOESN'T work - event is not defined.

I have the above code inside a module-global function in my actual scripts, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: It looks like you're relying on the global event object available in some browsers, which you shouldn't, and why are you passing it to the event handler that way at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `event` in your first example you're probably referring to `window.event`, which is assigned in some browsers to the last event that was raised:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html

As mentioned in the comments, you probably shouldn't rely on this because it's non-standard and (IMHO) super-confusing.

Anyway, in your first case `window.event` will be the `ready` event that jQuery is responding to, not the `click` event that you probably want to handle (http://jsfiddle.net/XLhL9/1/).

If you're in a `setInterval` callback then it looks like `window.event` is not defined at all, presumably because the browser is not currently handling an event. You can see this in http://jsfiddle.net/ujR5p/.

If you *really* wanted to access the `ready` event in your `setInterval` callback the trick would be to get the value of `window.event` inside the `ready` callback, assign it to a variable and then refer to that variable in your timeout callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // event is defined here, so assign it to a variable
    var theEvent = event;
    isSVGloaded = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (SVGloaded) {
            // event is no longer defined, but theEvent still is:
            $("#score svg").mousedown(theEvent.data, scoreDrag);
            window.clearInterval(isSVGloaded);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

But it sounds like what you really want is the `mousedown` event. Fortunately jQuery makes this super easy to access:

```
var scoreDrag = function (eventObject) {
    // jQuery will pass the `mousedown` event in as `eventObject`
    // see http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/#mousedown-handler
    alert('X: ' + eventObject.pageX + ' Y: ' + eventObject.pageY);
};
```

Could you perhaps avoid this `setInterval` by executing this code on [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of ready? Or by raising a custom event?

Comment: Yes! How I could be so naive - is beyond me. Let this be a lesson to all nascent programmers who don't understand event handling that patient strangers can and will help them on the internet. THANK YOU.

Comment: Don't worry about it! You've strayed into a really confusing bit of browser behaviour there. Do you actually need `event.data`? If you're not using it in `scoreDrag` just omit it and call `$("#score svg").mousedown(scoreDrag);`.

Comment: I'm not totally sure. Omitting the event.data argument has no effect on the handlers functionality. But I do need to know the coordinates of the event and whether the cmd/ctrl key was depressed on mousedown. So it appears that no, I do not need access to event.data.

Comment: Ahhh, in my examples the `event` is the `ready` event, not the click event. The click event will be passed in by jQuery as the first parameter to `scoreDrag`. No need to touch the global `event` at all. I'll edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Okay. My big problem was that I was trying to pass the undefined global `event` object in my `mousedown` handler - so the handlers weren't getting assigned. But now that that's out of the way things are much smoother sailing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shure that your first script do not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#score svg").mousedown(event.data, scoreDrag);
});
```

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#score svg").mousedown(
          function(event){
              alert('Mouse down');
          }
    );
});
```

Comment: I think the first one _would_ work (it will call `mousedown([eventData], handler)` with whatever `event.data` happens to be), but it's probably not doing what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, could be - but `event` seems to be `undefined`. It is like you wrote in your answer: `window.event` could be defined in IE

Comment: Yeah, sounds like `window.event` should be avoided completely. All part of the fun of developing in the browser I suppose.